# jQuery .hide() -- sliding elements left

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, show-hide

I'm fixing my nav to the top of the page. I'm using Bootstrap (CSS only). I'm using jQuery to hide one logo (`img` class `.logo`) and show another (`img` class `.logo-sm`), on scroll.

Everything basically works, except for one thing. The hiding function slides the main logo to the left as it fades out, but I'd like it to slide up. I'm pretty sure this is not `.hide()` function's default behavior, but I don't know jQuery very well so I'm not sure how to change it.

I built a JSFiddle to demonstrate the behavior. It doesn't work consistently for some reason (it does locally), but you can see the logo sliding left the first time you scroll down.

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSDesign/7evccubm/)**

The script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// nav fixing
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
        $(".logo").hide(100);
        $(".logo-sm").show(200);
    } else {
        $(".logo").show(100);
        $(".logo-sm").hide(200);
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.hide()` only sets the `display` of the element to `none`. It doesn't animate. That behavior is probably caused by having transitions in your CSS.

If you want to animate the element with jQuery, you can use `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // nav fixing
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
            $(".logo").slideUp(100);
            $(".logo-sm").slideDown(200);
        } else {
            $(".logo").slideUp(100);
            $(".logo-sm").slideDown(200);
        }
    });
});
```

But you've got some other stuff going on in your fiddle that is causing some weirdness so this won't work much better. I would suggest not animating with jQuery, but use it to change classes on the elements and handle the animation with CSS transitions. Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // nav fixing
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > 1){
            $(".logo").removeClass("showing");
            $(".logo-sm").addClass("showing");
        } else {
            $(".logo-sm").removeClass("showing");
            $(".logo").addClass("showing");
        }
    });
});
```

And then style the `.showing` class with transitions.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because .show() is applying display: inline-block when what you need is display: block.

To fix this, you need to find what's setting the header .logo css display value to be inline and change it to block. From the jquery api, show will set the display property to whatever it was set to initially. In this case, it's inline-block which is why your logo is moving to the left.

Comment: I see that now. It's strange because I'm not adding it anywhere. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Upvote for correct answer + explanation of the sliding effect